# Noncoalescing and bouncing droplets

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, water, fluid-statics

if you set a dish filled with water onto a loudspeaker or other vibrator and make vibration, When it oscillates, it is possible to hold small droplets on its surface for a long time. I mean, when you put a droplet of water on vibrating water surface, it doesn't coalesce with the water and bounce on the surface of water.( see this video https://youtu.be/KZ5ZLPWasrM )

As we know, drop reaches its minimal potential when coalescing with water ( that's why drops coalesce)

what exactly cause this? why doesn't the drop coalesce with the water?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This phenomenon is described in the paper:

> Couder, Y., et al. "From bouncing to floating: Noncoalescence of drops
>   on a fluid bath." Physical review letters 94.17 (2005): 177801. ([PDF](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Emmanuel_Fort/publication/7837945_From_bouncing_to_floating_noncoalescence_of_drops_on_a_fluid_bath/links/0046351e54fd772dcf000000.pdf))

To quote the opening paragraph:

> Intuition expects the merging of two volumes of the same fluid when
>   they come into contact with each other. This is also expected by
>   physics. As the two free surfaces come close, a van der Waals
>   attractive force tends to bring them into contact. As soon as this
>   contact is effective, surface tension leads to a minimization of the
>   interface area and to merging. This coalescence is usually slightly
>   delayed by the need for air to flow out of the intermediate region.

In other words, coalescence involves the escape of interstitial air which takes a finite amount of time. So if you 'kick' the drop away from the surface in less time than it takes for this process to complete, then the drop won't coalesce.