# Noncoalescingِ drops on vibrating liquid surface

Tags: fluid-dynamics, surface-tension, fluid-statics

if you set a dish filled with soapy water onto a loudspeaker or other vibrator and make vibration, When it oscillates, it is possible to hold small droplets on its surface for a long time. I mean, when the liquid surface starts vibrating, some drops of the same liquid, Spontaneously appear on the surface of the liquid.

What causes this phenomena? Why do the drops appear?

This is different from [another question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/244938/noncoalescing-and-bouncing-droplets) . the defference :

In this question some drops will be ***created Spontaneously *** 
But in the other question drops wich are ***put*** on the vibrating surface won't coalesce.

Comment: I'm guessing it is because the surface of the droplet doesn't have time to settle and merge with the rest of the soapy water.  These things happen quickly to notice with the naked eye, but it doesn't happen instantaneously.  Evidently, the vibrating motion is preventing the merge by constantly bouncing the droplet away from the surface.

Comment: NOOOOOOOO. That's another question

Comment: That question is defferent

Answer (score 0):

Surface tension plays a key role in this phenomenon as far as I know , when the liquid starts vibrating and a part of liquid (any shape) is thrown up and because of surface tension it transforms into a droplet so as to reduce it's surface area(since for a given volume sphere has the least surface area) . This phenomenon is not possible with pure water (unless you mix soap.